# Adding object properties using functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am currently learning functional programming using Underscore.js. What I want to do is add two co-ordinates together. Let P1 = (0, 0) and P2 = (1, 1). Therefore, P1 + P2 = (1, 1)

I have a solution, but it seems so convoluted that I'm sure I'm doing something wrong:

```
// Base 2D Cartesian Point
var Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.add = function(delta) {
  return _.object(_.keys(this),
    _.map(
      _.zip(
        _.values(this), 
        _.values(delta)), 
        function(point) {
          return _.reduce(point, 
            function(memo, num) { return memo + num; }, 0);
        }
    )
  );
}
```

Is this the proper implementation of the add function for points using Underscore.js or is there a better solution?

Comment: What prevents you from simply adding two points together using ordinary Javascript arithmetic?

Comment: I had that originally, but for some reason, I had this feeling that it could be done with reduce or map somehow. I guess if I just added two points together it would be the easiest, but I figured there was some way to use the functional language to implement this. I'm a complete noob at functional programming, so I'm not sure what's the best way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning functional programming doesn't mean to forget what you already know.  For fixed two-dimensional coordinates, I would just use the following:

```
sum = [p1[0] + p2[0], p1[1] + p2[1]]
```

If you don't know the dimension of your coordinates, or if it's large, the next best in this case is to use a *list comprehension*, which for some reason a lot of people forget about, or don't think it's "functional enough," because it resembles a for loop.  However, it is more powerful than a for loop as it is an expression that can be assigned, can be evaluated lazily, and is parallelizable if you don't introduce side effects.

```
sum = (p1[i] + p2[i] for i in [0..(p1.length - 1)])
```

If you had a bunch of these to do, like addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. you typically would create a function to do the iteration, which takes another function as an argument for what you want to do to each pair.  It would look like this:

```
corresponding = (p1, p2, f) -> f(p1[i], p2[i]) for i in [0..(p1.length - 1)]
```

And you would use it like this:

```
sum  = corresponding(p1, p2, (i, j) -> i + j)
diff = corresponding(p1, p2, (i, j) -> i - j)
prod = corresponding(p1, p2, (i, j) -> i * j)
```

Granted, that's not much shorter than the list comprehension, but a real world `corresponding` function would probably be significantly longer due to error handling.

Note that these examples are in [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/), as I'm not familiar with underscore.js, but the solutions are fairly typical of functional programming.

Comment: I didn't know about List Comprehension. It looks very useful and definitely cleans it up a lot. Thanks for sharing this answer! It's very clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do functional programming on points, it would make more sense for your points to be lists of coordinates instead of objects.  That simplifies the code quite a bit:

```
function add(p1, p2) {
    _.map(_.zip(p1, p2), function(coords) {
        return _.reduce(coords, function(coord, sum) { return sum + coord; }, 0);
    });
}
```

This may make sense if you're dealing with ten dimensional space, but it seems like overkill for two dimensions.

Comment: I'm beginning to see how functional programming is a separation of data and methods. It does seem to promote a lot of reuse and separator of duty. Definitely takes a lot more thinking to generalize the methods, but I suspect that over time it will get easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you can use to perform this calculation. I am going to use your base 2d point object and extend it a couple of ways

```
// Base 2D Cartesian Point
var Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};
```

Since Robert Harvey's suggestion is so straight forward, let's start with it:

```
var startpoint = new Point(0, 0);
var offsetpoint = new Point(startpoint.x + 5, startpoint.y + 5);
```

Next, you can add a function to the Point instance already created:

```
Point.add = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
};
```

As you have shown above, you can also modify the class prototype by changing `Point.add` to `Point.prototype.add`. The revised declaration adds the `add` method to all Point instances.

Suppose you want to pass a Point instead of x and y? We can do that too. We just can't use a polymorphic method declaration. We can, however, morph the function into a new function with different parameters. The down side to this is that, from that point on, you will not ever be able to get back to the first implementation with x and y without replacing the function again. That's probably too much for right now. Let's add the next version:

```
Point.prototype.addPoint = function(anotherPoint) {
    // Is the object being passed in of our class?
    if(anotherPoint instanceof Point) {
      this.add(anotherPoint.x, anotherPoint.y);
    }
};
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azuckerman/HfK39/) with this code working.

Comment: With this, would it be better to take in two points to keep Point from being mutable?

Comment: That would be a matter of opinion. Everything in javascript is mutable, so I would think that it wouldn't matter.